# Selecting a value from a database an check if it is true or false

Tags: mkannotation

This code always returns true can some please help me out

```
public boolean plselct(String sqd)
    {
     try{
         String player  ;

         pm = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT playertype FROM playerdetails where idplayeratrr = ?");

         pm.setString(1,sqd );
         h= pm.executeQuery();

         player = h.getString("playertype");

         if ("Goal keeper".equals(player))
         { return true; }
         else 
           return false;

       }catch (Exception e)
        {}
    return false;
}
```

---

```
SelectQu p = new SelectQu();
p.plselct("77");

if(true)
{ System.out.println("Yes"); }
else 
{ System.out.println("No"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for `if(true)`?  Did you mean this instead:

```
SelectQu p = new SelectQu();

if(p.plselct("77"))
{ 
     System.out.println("Yes"); 
}
else 
{ 
    System.out.println("No"); 
}
```